# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 equivalent of the "label-important" class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the Bootstrap 3 equivalent of the following code?

```
<span class="label label-important">Important</span>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently, in Twitter Bootstrap 3, some of the CSS classes for labels have changed. The new ones are:

- `label-default`
- `label-primary` (new in Bootstrap 3)
- `label-success`
- `label-info`
- `label-warning`
- `label-danger` (used to be `label-important`)

In addition, `label-inverse` was removed altogether from Bootstrap 3.

Therefore, the Bootstrap 3 equivalent to the code in the question would be:

```
<span class="label label-danger">Important</span>
```